# A problem on distributing indistinguishable balls into 10 different groups such that...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got this problem which I am stuck at for an hour and half:

Suppose that we have an infinite number of indistinguishable balls and we need to distribute them into 10 different groups such that

$ x_1<x_2<x_3<...<x_{10}$

Where $x_i$ denotes the number of balls in the i-th group

And the number of balls in the 10-th group must be less than or equal to $20$ (I.e. $x_{10}\leq 20$)

How many such distributions are there?
(Note: the number of balls in the 1-th group can be zero (i.e. $x_1=0$))

Examples for such distributions:
$0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9$ (the first)
$0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10$
...
$11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20$ (The last)

I tried some ways but none led me to a solution.

Any hint/help will be appreciated.

Comment: But if we have an infinite number of balls, we can't possibly fit them all into a finite number of finite sets. Are we not supposed to distribute *all* the balls?

Comment: Yes, we aren't supposed to distribute all the balls into the groups, but we suppose that we have no limit on how many balls we can distribute into the groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $0 \le x_1<x_2< \cdots < x_N\le M$  (with $N=10$, $M=20$).

Define $$\begin{array}{}
y_0&=& x_1 \\ 
y_1&=&x_2-x_1-1\\
y_2&=&x_3-x_2-1\\
&\cdots&\\
y_{N-1}&=&x_N-x_{N-1}-1\\
y_N&=&M-x_N
\end{array}$$

Then any $\{y_i\}_{i=0\cdots N}$ defines a valid configuration (and viceversa) iff $y_i\ge0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{N} y_i =M-(N-1)=S$

The number of these configurations is given ([stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)) by

$$ {S+(N+1)-1 \choose S}={M+1 \choose N}$$

In our case: ${21 \choose 10}=352,716$

Comment: Thank a lot. Now I understand the solution.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, fixed

Comment: By the way ${21\choose 10}=352,716$ and not $3,879,876$ As written in the answer.

Comment: @Saita Sigh, not my best day.. .fixed.